# android simple download ,no bar or other messages

Tags: android, android-intent, download

I tried to make a simple button which accept the terms of the application. And with pressing this button to switch to another screen. But inacelasi time adaptation and download application. If there are new .apk download it. If there is no download.
Unfortunately not go as I wanted, give much that sucks.
I tried to use other examples given forum but unfortunately we could not fit them.

```
>    private void accepttermenibuton() {
>         Button accionentrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAccept);
>         accionentrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void onClick(View v) {
>                 startActivity(new Intent(Termeni.this, Categori.class));
>                 startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://ggg.comm/apk.V1.1.apk")));
>             }
>         });
>     }
```

How can I do to download a fisier.apk without opening in chrome. I do not want anything complicated, very simple to understand myself.
Only to download this file, but without opening the chrome, I do not want to open a page in chrome.
Thank you.

Comment: I could not understand your question. Could you use Google Translate and make it an English version?

Comment: How can I do to download a fisier.apk without opening in chrome. Dara do not want anything complicated, very simple to understand myself.
Only to download this file, but without opening the chrome, I do not want to open a page in chrome.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We did, but do not know where download, download folder, the file is not downloaded, and if I get to open the download manager gives me erroare package, although always download the files.

```
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.app.DownloadManager.Query;
import android.app.DownloadManager.Request;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.File;

public class Upgrade extends ActionBarActivity {
    private long enqueue;
    private DownloadManager dm;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upgrade);

        BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
                    long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(
                            DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
                    Query query = new Query();
                    query.setFilterById(enqueue);
                    Cursor c = dm.query(query);
                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        int columnIndex = c
                                .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                        if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c
                                .getInt(columnIndex)) {


                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(
                DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Request request = new Request(
                Uri.parse("http://android.vrt.ro/tv-update/Virtual-Romania-Tv.(VRT).V5.apk"));
        enqueue = dm.enqueue(request);


    }

    public void showDownload(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS);
        startActivity(i);

        Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                .setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/download/Virtual-Romania-Tv.(VRT).V5.apk"),
                        "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        startActivity(promptInstall);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as you wanted.
There are two ways :-

1) Make use of HttpGet to request server with your API link "http://ggg.comm/apk.V1.1.apk". 
Search into google how to connect/request server to get data/response.

2) If you don't want to do that much work as directed in above point than use `DownloadManager` to get your apk file at your desired folder path .and every time check that path before downloading apk again to prevent redownload of that apk.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. but by chance you do not know a tutorial on using it? What I find is very complex and requires so.
Thank you again.  Can not give you a vote. I am not 15 yet to be able to vote. Excuse me.